# asp identity with int as TKey - UserId not found exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I have implemented custom UserStore and IdentityUser. I have changed the code so it uses int as key type.

The problem is that i leave key generation to database autoincrement field. Now, on Register, user is saved to db but framework doesnt have Id (its int default to 0) since it doesnt read any return values from db. (db did create new id autoincrement and saved it but framework dont have it)

Am i doing something wrong?

Questions:

1. Are we really suposed to do additional roundtrip to db (find by username, for example) just to get id?
2. Should we, on register, create one dummy record just to get Id and then update it with real data?

All of that feels very dirty.

Has anyone solved this problem?

UPDATE: Adding some code to it

**my IdentityUser:**

```
public class IdentityUser : IUser<int>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public bool IsEmailConfirmed { get; set; }
    public bool IsPhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }
    public int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }
    public bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LockoutEndDate { get; set; }
    public bool TwoFactorAuthEnabled { get; set; }

public IdentityUser()
    {
        //this.Claims = new List<Claim>();
        //this.Logins = new List<UserLoginInfo>();
    }

    public IdentityUser(int userId, string userName)
        : this()
    {
        this.Id = userId;
        this.UserName = userName;
    }
}
```

**my UserStore, CreateNew method:**

```
public Task CreateAsync(TUser user)
        {
            if (user == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("user", "User must not be null.");
            }

            _userDB.Insert(user);

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
```

so, a bit more of a description:

1) User clicks on Register

2) Gets prompted with register form

3) Submits Email, Password, ConfirmPassword

4) Record gets created in DB

5) Now the problem comes here, in Account/Register:

```
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {

                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);
```

**user** parameter in SignInAsync does not have Id (it has int default value of 0) because, obviously, it didn't get back the value of ID that SQL db assigned to it through auto-increment.

Comment: update your post with some code.. Which will help to find where you went wrong.!!??

Comment: thank you for your comment. i've updated the question.